# search all instagram users by searching with query

Tags: instagram, instagram-graph-api

I have to fetch all instagram users by using @mentions,Please point me to exact end point of Instagram graph api.

Previously I have seen below end point, but it is deprecated it seems

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=test&access_token

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Business Discovery endpoint if you wish to get the details of other users.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/17841405309211844?fields=business_discovery.username(username-you-wish-to-find){followers_count,media_count}&access_token={your-access-token}
```

Please refer to the developer's guide from the below link
[LINK]: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/business-discovery

You can even refer to this if you want to find mentions for your personal account
[DOC]: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/mentions

Comment: Thanks @Akash Sahu, but I want auto fetch feature, like by providing username, it needs to fetch all users which starts with those characters,
eg: if I start giving "@apple" , I need all usernames which start with that word.
We have similar end point for facebook, 
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/search/pages?q=apple
But I did not find similar feature api end point for Instagram.

Comment: Hi @SureshKumar Did anyone find the answer to it?

Comment: any leads on this @ahsan_cse2004